# npm run serve throwing errors over missing FilterService.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, node-modules

I'm working on a Project with Vue.js.

I have installed npm several times, but it keeps telling me that there are a couple of files that are not included in *node_module* folder.

Here are the errors I get when I try the `npm run serve`:

```
 error  in ./node_modules/primevue/api/FilterService.js

Syntax Error: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\guill\OneDrive\Escritorio\siis_frontend\node_modules\primevue\api\FilterService.js'
```

```
 error  in ./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.regexp.dot-all.js

Syntax Error: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\guill\OneDrive\Escritorio\siis_frontend\node_modules\core-js\modules\es.regexp.dot-all.js'
```

Something that I should mention is that a partner of mine does not have those folders nor files. But he is running the project properly with no problems.

Is there something I could do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with some basic troubleshooting steps.

1. Delete your *node_modules*-folder
2. Delete the *package-lock.json*-file
3. Navigate to the folder containing the *package.json*-file
4. Run *npm install*

Let me know if this solves your problem or not.